# How do I disable scientific notation of double values in IntelliJ debug view?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, double, scientific-notation

In IntelliJ, larger numbers are displayed with and "E" like this

> 2.6872193405846706E10

[image]

which makes it hard if you want to compare values with Excel for example.

How can I make IntelliJ to display values in a "human readable format"?

Answer (score 0):

Found out you can just create a custom Java Type Renderer that converts the double into a BigDecimal, which is displayed normally by adding

```java
new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(this))
```

[image]

And you can even format it this way

> 26,872,193,405.85

[image]

By adding a custom format somewhere in your code (in my case **Formats.java**)

```java
    public static final NumberFormat DEFAULT_BIG_DECIMAL_FORMAT;

    static{
        DEFAULT_BIG_DECIMAL_FORMAT  =  NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
        DEFAULT_BIG_DECIMAL_FORMAT.setGroupingUsed(true);
        DEFAULT_BIG_DECIMAL_FORMAT.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        DEFAULT_BIG_DECIMAL_FORMAT.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    }
```

and adding it to the Java Type Renderer in IntelliJ

[image]

**Don't forget the import by pressing ALT+ENTER**